# Validation conditions

Tags: php, input, conditional-statements

I would like to create a condition where if the values match the a success message appears then redirects the user to the index page, if the values don't match I want to stay on the current page and display an error message.

### login.php

```
 <?php
        //If input set then check if user input matches store details
        if(isset($_POST) and $_POST)
        {
            $success = false;
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            $success = login($_POST['email'],$_POST['pass']);
            //If successful display alert, redirect to index page
            if(isset($success))
            {
                $success = true;
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login successful\nRedirecting now.')</script>";
                header('Location: index.php');
                die();
            }
            //If unsuccessful display alert
            else
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login failed!')</script>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

### configure.php

```
<?php   
//Define constants
define("EMAILAD", "hello@domain.com");
define("PASSWORD", "pwd");

//Create function to compare input to constants
function login($email, $pass)
{
    $success = false;
    if(($email == EMAILAD) && ($pass == PASSWORD)) 
    {
        $success = true;
    }   
    return $success;
}?>
```

At the moment all it does is redirect me to the index page, could someone let me know where I've gone wrong, please?

Comment: you're outputting before header, for one thing. And that `login()` function's unknown as is the form for it

Comment: ok, someone popped an answer down there; ask them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why does the output before header matter? Also, the form's not important as that part works. In regards to Majorlogic's comment, I'm avoiding AJAX.

Comment: ok well whatever.

Comment: @Fred-ii- whatever what?

Comment: *"In regards to Majorlogic's comment, I'm avoiding AJAX"* - Don't tell "me" that, tell "them" that. I'm not your messenger.

Comment: whatever, whatever. You say the echo doesn't matter, ok.. whatever you say. You're right, I'm wrong and I don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it won't let me tag them in it, that's all. sorry...

Comment: You need to post a comment under the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42350686/1415724; that's how it's done. Edit: You've been given another answer now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Now, seeing that the other answer didn't fix your question, you should be posting what the custom `login()` function does, because it's starting to be guesswork. In the meantime, see what error reporting has to say http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and make sure that the form doesn't have anything to do with it. Sometimes people think that the little details don't count.

Comment: You cannot avoid AJAX if you want to stay on the same page without a reload.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll add it now, also it turns out I forgot to upload the fix to the server haha

Comment: @JayBlanchard Seems to have worked for me without AJAX.

Comment: Seeing the edit: where are you including/requiring that `configure.php` file? I don't see it. and did you run error reporting?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's in another file called header.php, want me to show that as well?

Comment: no it's ok, seeing you accepted the answer below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okie dokie, sorry for being vague and stuff earlier - thank you for the tips :)

Comment: Btw. The answer that was given about the ajax, was most likely posted because you included the javascript tag, which I removed just now. and you're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset()` will always be true as you set it twice. Instead, check the variable itself.

```
if ($success)
```

Comment: I've just tried that and it's not made any difference.

Comment: Make sure that the return value from `login()` returns true on successful logins.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I forgot to reupload the change to server haha. It doesn't seem to give me the confirmation message though. It gives me the warning that the input is incorrect and resets the page so that bit works

Comment: Most likely because it's you're trying to echo data and then redirect. In PHP, this is generally gives you errors as you are not allowed to output any data before using a header function. I would recommend doing away with the message itself, or showing the user the message on the index.php once it loads.

Comment: Oh ok, how would I do it for the login.php load then?

Comment: Set a cookie or session on success. On index.php you check if it exists then show the user an alert message.

Comment: Is it possible to use another type of message for the success instead of using a JS alert?

Comment: On success index.php load, yes, any you like. Before that, no.

Comment: I've figured out how to use a session in both pages but I don't know how to store the JS inside the session - any ideas?

Comment: You don't store JS inside a session. You simply set a session then check if it exists. If it exists, echo the JS you want to use.

Comment: I understand, what would I name the session or doesn't it matter?
I've seen examples of:
Session_Start();
$Session['name'] = '';

Comment: Always use `session_start();` once at the beginning when referencing or defining any `$_SESSION`.

Comment: I've added `session_start();

` followed by `$_SESSION['email'] = 'hello@domain.com';` 

and then put 

`if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Login successful.')</script>";
            }` on my login page but it's not displaying the alert.

Comment: I would recommend starting a new question for this as I cannot know where the issue lies without seeing the code and this is not the original issue. Good luck.

Comment: [Here's the link for the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352579/session-start-js-alert)